# How do I know when the user can scroll a RichTextBox with forced ScrollBars

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, scrollbar, richtextbox

I need the ScrollBars to be set to `ForcedBoth` but I also want to know when the ScrollBars' handles are visible and the user can scroll.

A boolean for both scrollbars would do

Here the user cannot scroll:
[image: Here the user cant scroll]

Here they can:
[image: And here they can]

I am trying to create a custom scrollbar derived from RichTextBox.
I am doing this by overlaying panels over the original scrollbar and disabling them (so you can use the original scrollbar), while getting different visuals (the overlayed panels).
I got everything working, except that I need to disable one of the panels (the handle panel) when the ScrollBars of the RichTextBox are disabled.

I tried `GetScrollInfo` from Win32 API but it results in inconsistent results when zooming into the RichTextBox or removing a bunch of lines at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is actually what you need to know about the state of the ScrollBars of your RichTextBox, use [GetScrollBarInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollbarinfo) to get this information, then test the values stored in the `rgstate` component of the returned [SCROLLBARINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-scrollbarinfo) struct.

- When a ScrollBar is disabled, `rgstate[0]` is set to `STATE_SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE`; the value at index 2 (page element), should be set to `STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE` in this case.
- When a ScrollBar is not present, the same value is `STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE`
- Otherwise, it's `0` (here, set to `SBIdObj.STATE_SYSTEM_AVAILABLE = 0x00000000`)

A sample method that can be used to test the ScrollBars. Call it as, e.g.,

```
var result = GetScrollBarsState(myRichTextBox.Handle);
```

It returns a named tuple with the state of both ScrollBars set to the current  `SBIdObj` value

```
public (SBRgState Vertical, SBRgState Horizontal) GetScrollBarsState(IntPtr controlHandle)
{
    var sbi = new SCROLLBARINFO() { cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<SCROLLBARINFO>() };

    bool result = GetScrollBarInfo(controlHandle, SBIdObj.OBJID_VSCROLL, ref sbi);
    if (!result) throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve vertical ScrollBar info");
    var vert = (SBRgState)sbi.rgstate[0];

    result = GetScrollBarInfo(controlHandle, SBIdObj.OBJID_HSCROLL, ref sbi);
    if (!result) throw new Exception("Failed to retrieve horizontal ScrollBar info");
    var horz = (SBRgState)sbi.rgstate[0];
    return (vert, horz);
}
```

---

Declarations:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetScrollBarInfo(IntPtr hWnd, SBIdObj idObject, ref SCROLLBARINFO psbi);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SCROLLBARINFO {
    public int cbSize;
    public Rectangle rcScrollBar;
    public int dxyLineButton;
    public int xyThumbTop;
    public int xyThumbBottom;
    public int reserved;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public int[] rgstate;
}

// GetScrollBarInfo idObject
public enum SBIdObj : uint {
    OBJID_HSCROLL = 0xFFFFFFFA,
    OBJID_VSCROLL = 0xFFFFFFFB,
    OBJID_CLIENT = 0xFFFFFFFC
}

// SCROLLBARINFO rgstate flags
[Flags]
public enum SBRgState {
    STATE_SYSTEM_AVAILABLE = 0x00000000,
    STATE_SYSTEM_UNAVAILABLE = 0x00000001,
    STATE_SYSTEM_PRESSED = 0x00000008,
    STATE_SYSTEM_INVISIBLE = 0x00008000,
    STATE_SYSTEM_OFFSCREEN = 0x00010000,
}
```