# How can I auto scroll down when a new line is added to a multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I auto scroll down a `TextBox` after setting a `TextBox` to a `string[]` only if the user was already scrolled to the bottom of the `TextBox` before there was a new message added to it?

I have a multiline `TextBox` and every so often I check with my server to see if there are any new messages to be delivered, when there are, it gives me back a `string[]` with the message history. I then set the multiline `TextBox` to the new `string[]` like this:

```cs
output.Lines = messages;
```

`output` is the multiline `TextBox`, and `messages` is a `string[]`.
This works but when you're talking with someone, you need to scroll down every time they send a new message. I tried auto scrolling down when the `TextBox` was updated, but then I would get scrolled down if someone was sending messages, even if I didn't want that.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743448/auto-scrolling-text-box-uses-more-memory-than-expected) but I couldn't use the `AppendText()` method because I was putting in a `string[]` when replacing the `AppendText()` method with `output.Lines = messages;`, it ended up scrolling down repeatedly even when I was scrolled far up the `TextBox`

When I tried with the `AppendText()` method, it still gave me problems by not scrolling down at all when I added a new message:

```cs
output.AppendText(myNewMessage + Environment.NewLine)
```

As a recap of what I want to do, I will try to make my question as clear and simple as possible:

How can I use code to automatically scroll down to the bottom of a multiline `TextBox` after adding a new line to the `TextBox` if the scroll bar was already at the bottom of the `TextBox` before adding a new line?

Comment: [How to scroll a RichTextBox control to a given point regardless of caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65222953/7444103) or [How do I know when the user can scroll a RichTextBox with forced ScrollBars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74017343/7444103), depending on what you want to do, it's not exactly clear from your description

Comment: It sounds like your user has a separate input box where they type messages to be sent to the customer or whoever. And that your main text box includes a mixture of texts from both sources. But you only want the autoscroll when a new entry is from the customer and not from your user. If at all possible, can your server remember a flag when a new text is added from a customer (only)? That will be the most reliable method. Then you can safely auto-scroll.

Comment: Yes thank you, I forgot to mention that I only update the textbox when there is a new message from any source.